# Using Tabulate for 3-way table

Tags: sas

I am trying to output a three way frequency table. I am able to do this (roughly) with proc freq, but would like the control for variable to be joined. I thought `proc tabulate` would be a good way to customize the output. Basically I want to fill in the cells with frequency, and then customize the percents at a later time. So, have count and column percent in each cell. Is that doable with `proc tabulate`?

Right now I have:

```
proc freq data=have;
table group*age*level / norow nopercent;
run;
```

that gives me e.g.:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
proc tabulate data=ex1;
  class age level group;
  var age;
  table age='Age Category', 
        mean=' '*group=''*level=''*F=10./ RTS=13.;
run;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly get close to that.  You can't really get in 'one' cell, it needs to write each thing out to a different cell, but theoretically with some complex formatting (probably using CSS) you could remove the borders.

You can't use VAR and CLASS together, but since you're just doing percents, you don't need to use MEAN - you should just use N and COLPCTN.  If you're dealing with already summarized data, you may need to do this differently - if so then post an example of your dataset (but that wouldn't work in PROC FREQ either without a FREQ statement).

```
data have;
do _t = 1 to 100;
  age = ceil(3*rand('Uniform'));
  group = floor(2*rand('Uniform'));
  level = floor(5*rand('Uniform'));
  output;
end;
drop _t;
run;

proc tabulate data=have;
  class age level group;
  table age='Age Category', 
        group=''*level=''*(n='n'  colpctn='p')*F=10./ RTS=13.;
run;
```

This puts N and P (n and column %) in separate adjacent cells inside a single level.

Comment: So, I just used the proc tabulate code without the do loop and it turned out fine. I fear I am too novice to comprehend what is going on in the do loop. Thanks (as always) @Joe!

Comment: The Do loop bit was just making up fake data.  Any time I make a dataset `have`, it's the data you should already have.